# Iptables -gw parameter

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, tcp, route

I want to copy tcp traffic. i want to use these commands

```
 "  iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --dport 7 -j ROUTE --gw 1.2.3.4 --tee
 iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --sport 7 -j ROUTE --gw 1.2.3.4 --tee"
```

like stated here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247668/duplicate-tcp-traffic-with-a-proxy

but iptables keeps telling me "iptables v1.4.8: unknown option '--gw'"

What can I do to fix this?

With Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands you gave don't work because they are not a part of netfilter nor of the Linux kernel. They are unofficial patches which have never been included in Linux.

As for what you can do to fix this, that depends on what it is you are trying to accomplish, but you were far too vague on that point to offer any advice.

Comment: Yes indeed, I have the right version off ip tables, but my kernel doesn't support the --tee command :(